# Asking about someone's hometown

Tags: idiomatic-language

Which is correct of the following?

1. What is your hometown?
2. Where is your hometown?
3. What is the name of your hometown?

To me only no.3 sounds correct, just needs a second opinion. Thank you.

Comment: Just my opinion: All three sound acceptable to me.

Answer (score 2):

All three are grammatically correct. The first and third ask what is the name of the hometown. The second asks for the location of the hometown. So which is correct depends on what kind of answer you want.

Answer (score 1):

All three are grammatically correct.
The meaning of 2 is different; it asks for the location rather than the name of the hometown.
Native speakers would almost always prefer 1 instead of 3. The words 'the name of' are redundant. That **is** the information 1 is asking for.